# What to do about an 'illegal Choice' error in views?

Tags: views

I have a view with an exposed filter and it isnt working correctly.  I am trying to change the options on the exposed filter but all that happens is I get is 'An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator. '  I cant find anything logging anywhere.  This error is incredibly vague and tells me nothing about which choice is illegal or what legal options may be.

Is there somewhere this may be logged that I am not looking?

Comment: Re-do the same view from scratch and see if you still end up with the same error. You can use [simplytest.me](https://simplytest.me/project/drupal) just to make sure it is not just your Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

> 'An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site
>   administrator. '

This type of issue generally arises when, for example, you have 2-3 select list, select list 'second' is dependent on 'first' select list. Now if you get empty result (say) in your first select list, second select list will not get populated correctly and throw this type of exceptions.

This is just an example so that you might get an idea, the sequence of selecting values is not right.

Try the whole procedure again, and this message will get disappeared.